# The date that the final manuscript is due is in a few weeks. Should I get response now about if my paper was accepted or not?

Tags: peer-review, journals, special-issue

I submitted my paper on 1 July for the issue with these dates:

- deadline for submitting 31/7
- final manuscript due 15/11

I got a change in the date at "9/9 under review" then "28/9 with under review" until now.
Should I get notifications about acceptance or rejection during this duration as the final manuscript is due 15/11?

Note: The editors didn't reply to the email I sent before.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about journal acceptance dates cannot be answered without knowing all of the details, and even then only if one were part of the editorial process. As you tried to contact them by email, no one can give you a definite answer.

You do not tell us a lot. If this is a submission to a journal's special edition, then a final submission date is often tentative. I can speculate that the journal had difficulties finding reviewers as it took them more than a month to find some for you. This might explain why they did not yet have reviewed the paper. I can also speculate that the editorial process and the software that lets you track your submission are not synchronized.

At this moment, there is absolutely nothing you can do about this submission, (other than retracting your manuscript if you need a publication by a certain day and have a different outlet in mind that can actually provide an acceptance / rejection decision in time for you).

Comment: thanks  for the answer , all the dates i mentioned in the post in addition to publication will be at  Feb 2023 . excuse me , what is the expected time for changing the date or the status please

Comment: You will know when you get the acceptance/rejection letter, when it is in your mail box. There is nothing else we can say.